# Http Post not sending data to another page in angular js

Tags: php, angularjs, http, post

I am working on login form in Angular Js.The HTML and validation part is working fine.

The problem is when i send data using HTTP POST method to my servicecall PHP page and want to save it to DB.

I have tried all the way by setting this in JS

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

I have tried by setting enctype of form to

```
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

as well.But none of them is working i am not able to get data via $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET any of these method.

I have also tried using PHP library function.

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

But it gives some weird string which i can't handle because number of `POST`  data could be hundreds.

So this there any other way to solve the problem.

Code for `http` request is

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'servicecall.php',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: { 
            username: $scope.loginData.username,
            password: $scope.loginData.password,
            action : 'checkLogin'
        }  //First way of sending data

//Second way of sending data which is also not working
//data: "{username:"+$scope.loginData.username+",password:"+$scope.loginData.password+",action:checkLogin}" 

}  

$http(req).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);  
   }, function(response){
        alert("Error "+response);
   });
```

At PHP page i do

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($_POST);
```

But it prints just blank array like `array{}`

Comment: Can we see the full `$http({})` object. I suspect that there's an issue with how you're formatting the data before sending it to the server.

Comment: Please provide the code of $http call. Seems there is an issue.

Comment: can you add code snipet

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have added http code as well.

Comment: what are you getting in your console?

Answer (score 1):

Following the code that I am using for same purpose. Hope that may help you.

```
var app = angular.module('angularApp', []);

app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.login = function () {

            var request = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "login.php",
                data: {
                    email: $scope.email,
                    password: $scope.password
                },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            });
            /* Successful HTTP post request or not */
            request.success(function (data) {
                if(data == "1"){
                    $scope.responseMessage = "Successfully Logged In";
                }
                else {
                    $scope.responseMessage = "Username or Password is incorrect";
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: No change in output producing same to mine.